# Bot Doesn't proceed after first prompt

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying out this simple example

```
    var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, 
    function (session) {
        session.send("Welcome to the dinner reservation.");
        builder.Prompts.time(session, "Please provide a reservation date and time (e.g.: June 6th at 5pm)");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.dialogData.reservationDate = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime([results.response]);
        builder.Prompts.number(session, "How many people are in your party?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.dialogData.partySize = results.response;
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Whose name will this reservation be under?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.dialogData.reservationName = results.response;

        // Process request and display reservation details
        session.send(`Reservation confirmed. Reservation details: <br/>Date/Time: ${session.dialogData.reservationDate} <br/>Party size: ${session.dialogData.partySize} <br/>Reservation name: ${session.dialogData.reservationName}`);
        session.endDialog();
    }
);
```

The expected result

should be - [image]

But i am getting result like this 
[image]

It's not prompting after first. So Any suggestion. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake by not putting code in array and i think this can be a common mistake done by new comers. So syntax is

`var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [...code_goes_here...]);`

So the final code would look like this:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function (session) {
        session.send("Welcome to the dinner reservation.");
        builder.Prompts.time(session, "Please provide a reservation date and time (e.g.: June 6th at 5pm)");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.dialogData.reservationDate = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime([results.response]);
        builder.Prompts.number(session, "How many people are in your party?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.dialogData.partySize = `enter code here`results.response;
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Whose name will this reservation be under?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.dialogData.reservationName = results.response;

        // Process request and display reservation details
        session.send(`Reservation confirmed. Reservation details: <br/>Date/Time: ${session.dialogData.reservationDate} <br/>Party size: ${session.dialogData.partySize} <br/>Reservation name: ${session.dialogData.reservationName}`);
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);
```